# PaX - for libs?

Tags: grsecurity

I have managed out how PaX works. But I can't let 'scrot' save screenshots due to `giblib error: Saving to file * failed`

How to change flags for libs? Exciting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hardened/PaX_Quickstart#Understanding_PaX

> When PaX enforces or relaxes a feature, it does so on the basis of the executable's flags, not those of the libraries it links against.

Comment: So what do I do? Relaxing scrot completely doesn't work.

Comment: @Napoleon I was pointing out that you can't apply PaX to libraries. If `paxctl -pemrxs scrot` doesn't work then that's probably a new question.